# Isomerisation of alkanes under Lewis acidic conditions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, catalysis, hydrocarbons

My textbook says:

> n-Alkanes on heating in the presence of anhydrous aluminium chloride and hydrogen chloride gas isomerise to branched chain alkanes.

But no mechanism is given. After a little research, I found this: https://goenkanscienceblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/suggested-mechanism-of-isomerisation-of-alkanes/

However, it doesn't explain the role of the HCl gas. Is the mechanism correct and if so, what is the role of HCl?

Comment: Interesting question, reminded me of the synthesis of adamantane, so I googled it. The answer along with lots of discussion can be found here - http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/1974/CS/CS9740300479 basically trace alkene is present in the alkane sample; AlCl3 abstracts Cl- from HCl, H+ protonates alkene to form carbocation which undergoes 1,2-alkyl shifts.

Comment: @orthocresol    Wouldn't the carbocation increases the number of carbons in the original alkane?

Comment: Don't get what you mean. The website you linked also goes via a carbocation intermediate.

Comment: @orthocresol     There methyl shift is within the alkane whereas here trace alkene is acting as carbocation.

Comment: e.g. in n-butane there is butene impurity - protonated to form butyl carbocation

Comment: @orthocresol    Thanks got it. Only last query : how does reaction further propagates. Am i right if I say that carbocation will take hydride from alkane thereby producing another carbocation and so on?

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Comment: @orthocresol So if we somehow prepare pure n-Butane, it definitely wouldn't show this reaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mechanism for **butane** is shown here, instead of a general n-alkane.

## Initiation

[image: initiation]

As the comments have mentioned,  it probably begins by the protonation of butene impurities.

The Lewis acid, $\ce{AlCl3}$, stabilizes the chloride ion from $\ce{HCl}$ when the $\ce{H}$ is used to protonate the butene.

A secondary carbocation is formed, which undergoes methyl shift to form a primary carbocation. I have no idea why a primary carbocation can be formed.

## Propagation

[image: propagation]

An alkane attacks the carbocation, and supplies a "hydride" to the carbocation to complete the carbocation.

Meanwhile, another carbocation is formed which also undergoes methyl shift to regenerate the carbocation at the beginning of this step.

## Termination

[image: termation]

I am going out of my way here to suggest a isobutyl chloride (1-chloro-2-methylpropane) termination product. I can't find other Lewis bases to complete the carbocation for the termination step.

Comment: So is this a first order reaction?

Comment: Maybe the initiation step involves a methyl and a hydride shift? That would explain the stability

Comment: Possibly the AlCl3 extracts a methyl anion from the main chain? That would explain the formation of a more branched alkane due to carbocation stabilisation by a hydride shift.