# Role of Lewis acid in synthesis of adamantane from bicyclic species

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, catalysis

What is the role of $\ce{AlCl3}$ in the following synthesis of adamantane? I'm guessing it functions as a Lewis acid, but I am unsure how the mechanism of the second step works, as there is no region of high electron density in the bicyclic species.

If a mechanism for the second step exists, I would greatly appreciate if someone could propose one.

[image: adamantane synthesis]

Image source: Wikipedia

Comment: Tada, found it: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57826/isomerisation-of-alkanes-under-lewis-acidic-conditions Not the same question, but related. The reference in my first comment ([*Chem. Soc. Rev.* **1974,** *3,* 479](https://doi.org/10.1039/CS9740300479)) hopefully contains more than enough info for an answer, if anybody is keen on writing an answer.

Comment: The carbocation rearrangement mechanism is here: Schleyer, et al., J. Am Chem. Soc., 1973, 95, 5769. Too much to draw and I don't want to lift it from the paper.