# Why can't a quaternary carbon product be obtained by alkane isomerization in presence of AlCl3 and HCl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons

This question actually deals with the reaction in another question: [Isomerisation of alkanes under Lewis acidic conditions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57826/isomerisation-of-alkanes-under-lewis-acidic-conditions). I have a further doubt, regarding this reaction my book says that a quaternary carbon cannot be generated. Why is this so? Also if a pure alkane is used without alkene traces will the reaction fail to take place?

Comment: You're going to have a hard time coming up with a mechanism by which you will generate said quaternary carbon center.

Comment: @Zhe using a tertiary alkene?

Comment: What is a "tertiary alkene"?

Comment: @Zhe I meant something like 2-methylprop-1-ene, though tertiary alkene is not the right term

Comment: An alkene can only provide a tertiary cation on protonation. How will you migrate another group to make a quaternary center in a favorable way unless the migrating group is already a quaternary center? Nevermind the steric implications here...

Comment: You're basically asking if you can t-butylethylene will undergo rearrangement under, say, hydrochlorination. [It can](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01042a030). But notice that you already started with a quaternary center.